# How we can take a snapshot from a 3d image

Tags: javascript, image, 3d, snapshot

I have a 3d Image, and want to get snapshot from this image. as displaying currently. I have tried to get the snapshot using canvas, and fabric js but we are not able to take image snaps.

we are getting blank screenshot only.

Please suggest how i can take snapshot from an image.

The DOM Element where image is creating , here  panoImage  is container Div.

```html
 
<div id="panoImage" style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;">  <div style="top:  0px;left: 0px;position:relative;-ms-touch-action: none;">
<div style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 533px; height: 400px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 0; user-select: none;">
<canvas width="533" height="400" id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</div>
<div style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 533px; height: 400px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 1000; user-select: none; cursor: auto;">
</div>
<canvas style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 533px; height: 400px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 900; user-select: none; visibility: hidden;" width="533" height="400" id="mycanvas"></canvas>
<div style="top:  0px;left: 0px;position:absolute;padding: 3px;visibility: hidden;z-index: 1100;"> Hotspot text!</div></div></div>
```

Comment: Show us the code you currently have for taking a screenshot which produces a blank image and perhaps we can modify it to correct it.

Comment: Hi csm_dev,we have add the DOM Element where image is creating.